# How to test Android EditTex for content

Tags: android, android-edittext, back, keyevent

After a user presses the Back button on a device, I'm looking to test an EditText for content.

If the EditText has no content (the user never typed anything or they typed some input and then removed it all by backspacing) then go back to the previous activity (screen).

Else, the EditText has content so fire an alertDialog to see if they want to "Discard" the EditText input and return to the previous activity (screen),

or "Cancel" the AlertDialog to return to the EditText and change/add to the existing input.

The code I have for the Back button press works fine to return to the previous activity (partial listing below):

```
public boolean onKeyPreIme ( int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // the key has been pressed down
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
```

I'm looking for help on how to link that code with the if/then logic for the EditText content test.  I started with:

```
final EditText todoEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CEditText);
    int sTodo = todoEditText.getText().toString().trim().length();
        if (sTodo == 0) {
            run code to hide the keyboard and go to the previous activity
        }
        else {
            run code to show the alertDialog
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm...why not pass the data to a String and just check if the string is empty?

```
String strTodo = todoEditText.getText().toString().trim();
if (!strTodo.isEmpty() && !strTodo.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
   // run code to hide the keyboard and go to the previous activity
} else {
   // run code to show the alertDialog
}
```

The bigger issue I have with what you have explained is how you are working with your data between Activities. Instead, use Intents and Extras to pass along data from one Activity to another. Pass your editText data to a string as I mentioned before in Extras to your next Activity, and in your next Activity use that data to determine flow. Don't keep an Activity on the stack so that you can return back to it and start using data that is already there, that is a bad idea. But if this is what you want to do, utilize Android's lifecycle and make your editText checks upon return to previous Activity in onResume().

Lastly, it sounds like you might need a listener too. Just in case you do, here it is.

```
todoEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

});
```

Comment: yes i saw the listener TextWatcher code and didn't want to have to use on, before  and after code.  For your answer though, the initial driver to do the EditText content test is that the user has pressed the Back button, not that they typed input for the EditText.  Thoughts?

Comment: First of all, why are you trying to persist data in an Activity on the backstack? You will have more issues than trying to figure out if text is still in the editText view (memory issues). Secondly, if you really want to do this, in onResume check the editText as I posted above and do what you wish.

Comment: newb to Android here.  If there is no input data in the EditText then I want to return the user to the previous activity (screen).  Are you saying I need to destroy the current activity with finish() before returning the user to the previous activity to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: I am saying pass the data along with extras and then use that data from extras to determine if where you want to be directed to. This will flow better than revealing an Activity that only checks for previously entered data and then transitioning to another Activity. I will update my answer to explain further.

Comment: I need to be more clear.  The first activity is a welcome screen.  The user clicks a menu item & an intent launches the second activity.  The user can then type input on an EditText line that is part of the screen view.  I'm looking for the String code to test the EditText line.  If the String > 0 because the user typed in some data on the EditText line & then they press the Back key, I'd like to show an AlertDialog.  If the String = 0 because the EditText line is empty & then the user presses the Back key I'd like to close the softkeyboard and go back to the previous (the welcome screen).

Comment: p.s. I'm not passing any data between the two activities.  When the user presses the Back button on the second activity, I'd like to test for any data the user might have input.  If data, launch the alertDialog.  If no data input, close the soft keyboard and return to the first activity.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

May handle the function in onStop or onDestroy will be better if you will return to the previous activity.
Then you can check if the EditText content is null.

```
String tmp = mEditText.getText().toString.trim();
if (null != tmp && !("").equals(tmp)) {
   //code
} else {
   //code
}
```